# How to run intent call to the number * # 9900 #

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open the Dial Intent with the code *#9900#. However the phone application always appears empty.

Here is my code:

```
public void limpiarLogCat(View view) {
    String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
    call("*" + encodedHash + "9900" + encodedHash); 
}

protected void call(String phoneNumber) {
        try {
        startActivityForResult(
        new Intent("android.intent.action.DIAL", Uri.parse("tel:"
                            + phoneNumber)), 1);
    } catch (Exception eExcept) {

    }
}
```

Also, I have declared `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` in my **manifest.xml**.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare dial intent-filter in manifest and don't need any permissions to ACTION_DIAL. Look for my implementation

```
private void startDialActivity(String phone){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

also is good to check is telephony supported on device

```
private boolean isTelephonyEnabled(){
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm != null && tm.getSimState()==TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY
}
```

**UPDATE :**
try to use

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("*9900#");
startDialActivity(encodedHash);
```

instead of

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
startDialActivity("*" + encodedHash + "9900" + encodedHash);
```

Comment: Thanks Basbous, I have declared this in my manifest. But the method does not work. Regards

Comment: Thanks Basbous, your method works with Uri.encode("*9900#") but does not work with Uri.encode("*#9900#"). Regards

Comment: Could anyone help me?

Comment: i think its illegal to dail '*#'.